# Kubuntu 20.04 wi-fi auto disconnect and forgot password in every suspending

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, suspend, disconnect

I hope I'm asking this to right place but I have a big problem since yesterday.

As you can see in title, when I suspend or close my laptop; it started to forget and disconnect my Wi-fi every time. This situation started yesterday and I don't know what to do, I also can't find anything to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried when booting, selecting an older kernel?  Does it work normally there?  (ie. the reason is because of a recent kernel patch, meaning you have the cause and can potentially file a bug on the regression (helping it get fixed) and work-around until it's solved).

Comment: I haven't tried but how can I do it? I mean where is this "kernel choosing" place?

Comment: At the `grub` screen you can select an older kernel from whatever is installed. How easy that is varies on your hardware (it's dead easy on my desktop, on a sony netbook it's more of a pain (it's encrypted and it requires me to hit <ESC> to show; if the `plymouth` (Kubuntu) logo & dots show it's too late)  Open up the *Advanced options for Ubuntu* and the lower numbers (5.4.0-) will be older kernels available.

Comment: I have tried it now- I'm writing all of these from an older kernel- and the problem still continues to occur unfortunately. System still asks wi-fi password and disconnects in sleeping/closing activity.

Comment: Any help guys, I couldn't solve it. :(